# How to transform into a table

Tags: r

I have the following list of header and numbers:

```
data <- read.delim(header=TRUE, text='cor 0.7688679 0.7877358 0.8490566 0.8349057 0.7783019')
> data<-as.table (data)
Error in as.table.default(data) : cannot coerce to a table
```

I would like to get the results into data as if I entered it as followed:

```
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
  cor 
0.7688679
 0.7877358
 0.8490566
 0.8349057
')
```

How can I transform it into the read.table format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could replace the space with `\n` using `gsub` and read with `read.table`

```
df1 <- read.table(text=gsub(' ', '\n', str1), header=TRUE)
```

Or without replacing with `gsub`, we `scan` the string, and then use `read.table`

```
df1 <- read.table(text=scan(text=str1, what='', quiet=TRUE), header=TRUE)
```

To convert to a `table` object

```
as.table(as.matrix(df1))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'cor 0.7688679 0.7877358 0.8490566 0.8349057 0.7783019'
```